# telerik node click and chart refresh

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using telerik treeview with telerik chart control. I want to refresh/reload the chart on node click. any sample for that ?

Please suggest how to show node related data on chart when user clicks Treeview node.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using C# or VB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many techniques are available for the treeview's Load on Demand:

- Client-Side
- Server-Side
- Web Service
- Page Methods

[Telerik's documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/programming/loadondemandmodes/defaultcs.aspx) is really complete, so I suggest you take a look at it.